# Is there a way to run a python chat server from my computer so the clients can join from their computers via another network?

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, chat

I wrote a chat server with `python and` `socket`. Clients can connect to it via the local network but i need the clients to be able to connect to the server from another networks. I tried using `0.0.0.0` for the host IP in the server and I got this error message when trying to connect to it via another network

```
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

This is my code for the server

```
import threading
import socket

host = "0.0.0.0"
port = 55555

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((host, port))
server.listen()

clients = []
usernames = []

print("Server is online and running......")


def broadcast(message):
    for client in clients:
        client.send(message)


def handle(client):
    while True:
        try:
            message = client.recv(1024)
            broadcast(message)
        except:
            index = clients.index(client)
            clients.remove(client)
            client.close()
            user = usernames[index]
            broadcast(f"{user} left the chat!".encode("ascii"))
            usernames.remove(user)
            break


def receive():
    while True:
        client, address = server.accept()
        print(f"Connected With {str(address)}")

        client.send("NICK".encode("ascii"))
        username = client.recv(1024).decode("ascii")
        usernames.append(username)
        clients.append(client)

        print(f"Username - {username}")
        broadcast(f"{username} just Joined the chat!".encode("ascii"))
        client.send("connected to the server!".encode("ascii"))

        thread = threading.Thread(target=handle, args=(client,))
        thread.start()


receive()
```

And this is the code for the client

```
import socket
import threading

username = input("Your username : ")

host = "172.28.0.2"
port = 12344

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect((host, port))


def receive():
    while True:
        try:
            message = client.recv(1024).decode("ascii")
            if message == "NICK":
                client.send(username.encode("ascii"))
            else:
                print(message)
        except:
            print("An error occurred!")
            client.close()
            break


def write():
    while True:
        message = f"{username}: {input('')}"
        client.send(message.encode("ascii"))


receive_thread = threading.Thread(target=receive)
receive_thread.start()

write_thread = threading.Thread(target=write)
write_thread.start()
```

Basically I need the clients to be able connect to the server that is running on my computer from their computers without a local network.

Answer (score 0):

The easist way is that your server can apply for a public IP in WLAN, not a private internal IP behind some router or NAT devices. It can also works if here is a relay server in public.

If you can't, then you need to do NAT traverse to pounch a hole, so that external clients can get in touch with the server which is behind router. For this, you can google and use TURN/STUN/ICE.